# How to check if dotnet restore was ok in ps1?

Tags: bash, docker, powershell, .net-core

I have dockertask.ps1 file with `dotnet restore` command, the question is how to make sure if it runs without errors???

Comment: Check `$LASTEXITCODE` right after running `dotnet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After executing a programm you can catch the exit code with `$?`, but only right after execution.

```
dotnet restore
ErrNo="$?"
if [ "$ErrNo" -ne 0 ]
then 
echo "error code ${ErrNo} received."
fi
```

`$?` includes the error code of the last execution.

The `if` command with `-ne` means **Not Equal**.